# Fiddler: Request was retried after Receive operation failed when connected with VPN

Tags: angular, apache, tomcat, vpn, fiddler

Fiddler is giving me the note: This request was retried after a Receive operation failed.

It gives me this note when I am into VPN and api takes more than 8-10 minutes to respond.

How is this error created, what does it mean and most important, is there a fix? Where exactly this retry logic resides.

I tried to set Keep-alive timeout for 3600 seconds but still not working

Comment: You can try to change the Fiddler-internal timeout values: https://groups.google.com/g/httpfiddler/c/7eAVDyJKP0Y

Comment: Robert- I am not sure about the trigger point of retry logic.